# Transfering contacts from one Android smartphone (with smashed screen) to another

Tags: contacts

So my mother in law used to have an Huawei ideos X3 (U8510) and due to an unfortunate event the screen of her smartphone got smashed. That wouln't be a big issue if it wasn't for the fact that she wasn't saving her contacts in the cloud on google servers, she was saving them only on the phone.

Since her screen is unresponsible to touches, I can't get her contacts into the google cloud.

I gave her my old Samsung Galaxy S with CyanogenMod but I can't get her contacts over there.

What I did so far is, root the Huawei phone through adk to gain access to all files and databases. So far so good. I extracted the database with the contacts (contacts2.db) and overwrote the contacts2.db from the Galaxy S, which resulted into major force closes when opening the contacts app.

Any other suggestions? She needs her contacts badly.

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266374/backup-full-sms-mms-contents-via-adb this is what you want...

Comment: @Tirath My question was not, how to pull the contacts from the phone using adb :-) because thats what I accomplished already. What I need to do is, transfer them to the new phone and make the contacts accessible to the same phone.

Comment: If you have already done then just put the file in SD and use this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netqin.contactbackup&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a third party app to get the contacts to PC?

Here is an example https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snappea, but there are more, pick one. Install it using adb and then access your phone from PC.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you have instructions for installing an app via adb? How would they download the app from the play store so it could be installed via adb? Wouldn't they need to launch the app as well?

Comment: sounds like a plan, I will try that today in the evening when I am at home.

Comment: First of all, you can find apps to download online, and it gets you the apk file.

Here is an example of how to run it from adb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109234/how-to-run-not-only-install-an-android-application-using-apk-file